# Behavior of Absolutely Positioned Child Div with Inline-Block Parent Div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've noticed some weird behavior on Chrome/FF/IE, and was wondering if anybody knew why HTML/CSS gets rendered in this way.

If you have an absolutely positioned child div, whose parent's display is set to inline-block, any white space in the child div is treated as a line break.  This is true even if the child element is set to contenteditable="true" (when you try to type spaces, it causes a line break).

Here is a fiddle of the phenomenon: http://jsfiddle.net/cnPAG/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Hello, World!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you either remove the fact that it is absolutely positioned, or the fact that the parent element is inline-block, the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you give absolute positioning to the child div (`#content`), you're removing it from the flow of the document, and therefore the parent div (`#container`) collapses, as it behaves as if it no longer contains anything, essentially having zero width or height. This causes the absolutely positioned child div (`#content`) to collapse. You can see a similar result if you remove your rules and give the parent a `width:0` rule.

```
#container {
    width:0px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cnPAG/4/)**

Comment: You're awesome! Another way to tell that your answer is definitely true, is if you leave my fiddle the way it is, and type exactly what is in the absolute div into the parent div.  The child div is then no longer collapsed. I will have to consider ways around this in my project (probably manually setting the parent div with jquery).  Thanks again!

Comment: I have a quick additional question. If the reason that it is collapsing, is because the absolute div has been taken out of the document flow, and the parent div is empty, why does the following fiddle not collapse, where position is relative in the parent, and absolute in the child: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cnPAG/5/)

HTML:
`<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Hello, World!</div>
</div>`

CSS:
`#container {
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
}`

Comment: Because in that example the divs are natively using display:block. The collapse happens when the parent is using inline or inline-block.

Comment: @Camden Reslink: If you set a border to each DIV you will easily see its dimensions - see [*updated JSFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/cnPAG/8/)